# Unable to redirect user to their profile after Google login using Passport and Auth0

Tags: node.js, redirect, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, mern

I have implemented a Google login functionality in my application using Passport and Auth0. The authentication process works fine, but I'm facing an issue with redirecting users to their profile page after a successful login. Instead of being redirected to the profile page, the user keeps landing on the homepage.

Here is the relevant code snippet for the callback function:

```
router.get(
  "/auth/google/callback",
  passport.authenticate("google", { failureRedirect: "/login" }),
  (req, res) => {
    // ... existing code ...

    // Redirect to the user's profile
    res.redirect(`${process.env.CLIENT_URL}/online-rest-client/${userObj.username}`);
  },
  userController.loginUser
);
```

Here is the relevant code snippet for react

```
const Login = () => {
  const { setUserDetails } = useContext(UserContext);
  const historySignup = useNavigate();
  const [buttonState, setButtonState] = useState({
    disabled: false,
    label: "Log In",
  });

  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });

  // const [records, setRecords] = useState([]);

  const handleinput = (e) => {
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;

    setUser({ ...user, [name]: value });
  };

  // when login button is clicked
  const handleLogin = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setButtonState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      disabled: true,
      label: "Logging In",
    }));
    axios
      .post(`${url}/users/auth`, user)
      .then((res) => {
        toast.success("Login Successful");
        historySignup("/request");
        setUserDetails((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          isLoggedIn: true,
          token: res.data.token,
          email: res.data.email,
          username: res.data.username,
          userId: res.data.session.userId,
        }));
        localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(res.data));
        setUser({ email: "", password: "" });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        toast.error(
          error.response ? error.response.data.errors[0].msg : error.message
        );
        setButtonState((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          disabled: false,
          label: "Log In",
        }));
      });
  };
```

The process.env.CLIENT_URL variable is set correctly, and I have verified that it contains the expected URL. However, the redirection doesn't seem to work as intended.

The process.env.CLIENT_URL variable is set correctly, and I have verified that it contains the expected URL. However, the redirection doesn't seem to work as intended.

I have also confirmed that the userObj.username value is correctly populated. Additionally, I'm generating a JSON Web Token (JWT) and including it in the user object for further authentication. I want it to redirect the user to their profile.